# How to install pip for certain version of python3 in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to run docker:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.6.1 as base
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/r.txt
RUN apt update && apt install -y python3.7

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 20 && \
    update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 40

RUN apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt install -y python3-pip gcc
```

The image  nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.6.1 has ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6 installed. I want to make image with python 3.7 as default.
But when I build container from the following image pip3 is from python 3.6. And after I run pip install it install all libraries for python 3.6.

```
root@localhost:/# pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

But I want that libraries to be for python 3.7.
I tried to delete python3.6 the docker file is:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.6.1 as base

RUN apt-get -y purge python3.6 && \
    apt-get -y autoremove

RUN apt-get -yqq update && \ 
    apt install -y python3.7 python3-pip gcc
```

But again pip3 is for python 3.6.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you can run  python3.7 -m pip install <package>

Comment: Thanks. It really works!